# How to get only the one record with the most latest date

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL:

```
select distinct name ,
            sets_name ,
            cast(from_unixtime(sets_starttimestamp) as date) ,
            cast(from_unixtime(sets_endtimestamp) as date) -- if there are few records then take only 
            the last date 
from cex 
where creator = '...';
```

The SQL will produce this output:

```
DEFECT  E4_S    2020-03-20  2020-06-30 
DEFECT  E4_S    2020-03-20  2020-12-31
DEFECT  E5_S    2020-03-27  2020-07-02 
DEFECT  E5_S    2020-03-27  2020-07-03
DEFECT  E6_S    2020-07-13  2020-10-01
```

What  I need to do is to get only the most (bigger) last end time. So the output will looks like:

```
DEFECT  E4_S    2020-03-20  2020-12-31
DEFECT  E5_S    2020-03-27  2020-07-03
DEFECT  E6_S    2020-07-13  2020-10-01
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `group by` and `max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the entries as follows

```sql
SELECT name,
       sets_name,
       cast(from_unixtime(sets_starttimestamp) AS date),
       MAX(cast(from_unixtime(sets_endtimestamp) AS date))
GROUP BY name, sets_name, cast(from_unixtime(sets_starttimestamp) AS date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much